# Disable Javascript validation in CGI::Formbuilder

Tags: javascript, perl, formbuilder

Creating a form with [CGI::Formbuilder](http://www.formbuilder.org/) generates a HTML page containing javascript to validate the fields (with an old-school style "alert" if the form is invalid) as well as back-end verification in Perl. Would anyone know how to turn off the javascript generation (so that I can use some other js libraries better eye candy, or even only use backend verification) ?

Thanks,
Manojo

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
my $form = CGI::FormBuilder->new(
    javascript => 0
);
```

As found in the [quick reference](http://www.formbuilder.org/download/CGI-FormBuilder-3.0501/docs/CGI/FormBuilder.html#quick_reference)

Comment: oops. didn't see the quick reference before, sorry. Thanks for the reply!